# Showing all Custom fields labels & values in a page

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla3.0, custom-fields, virtuemart

I want to showing custom fields labels and values of VirtueMart into a page. I am using VM Wish-list component. When user select any product with custom fields. Product will added in wish-list but custom fields values not showing on wish-list. so i want to showing those all fields name(labels) & Values. I have wondered all VM code as well but not able to found those triggers VM used for converting into custom values to product custom fields name(labels) and values.

Answer (score 0):

I have do it myself. Now from below code you will get all custom fields of VM product in any where in Joomla.

```
VmConfig::loadConfig();

require(VMPATH_ADMIN.DS.'models'.DS.'customfields.php');

$productDB = VmModel::getModel('product')->getProduct('put_your_product_id');
$getAllData->customfields = $productDB->customfields;
//print_r($getAllData); die('ssssssssss');
$product_attribute = VirtueMartModelCustomfields::CustomsFieldOrderDisplay($getAllData);

echo '<div>'.$product_attribute.'</div>';
```